# What does "Auto Loom All Thread" do?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

`o` (Orders) - `W` (Workshop Orders) - `l` (Auto Loom All Thread)

What does it do? Does it automatically create cloth from all thread and yarn available?

Comment: FYI: A [loom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loom) is a machine used to weave thread together.  That's why the label reads as it does.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, that's exactly what it does. It's useful, but it means it won't leave any thread for your hospital.

Comment: Does it do "Weave Cloth (Plant Thread)", "Weave Silk Cloth", "Weave Cloth (Wool/Hair Yarn)" and "Weave Metal Cloth" all together?

Comment: @CrabMan Yes, for pig tails, spider butt thread, hair, and adamantine strands.